# PHP - JQuery | Instant / Direct Search can't find PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I made at first a simple JQuery and PHP code for direct search.
I found a JQuery that is proffecinal showing the user search with nice design but I can't make the PHP code to make it search I need to know from where posts and other things I am not so good in jquery.
Also I get undefined I think can't get values from php I just need the values not the whole code for search

JQuery Code:

```
$("#quick-search-input").click(function(){
    $(".ac-results").css({
        left:$("#quick-search").position().left
    })
});
var s=$("#quick-search-input").val();
$("#quick-search-input").focus(function(){
    if(s==$("#quick-search-input").val()){
        $("#quick-search-input").val("")
    }
    else if($("#quick-search-input").val().length>2&&$(".ac-results ul").not(":empty")){
            $(".ac-results").slideDown()
    };
    $(".ac-results").css({
        left:$("#quick-search").position().left
    })
});
$("#quick-search-input").blur(function(){
    if($("#quick-search-input").val().trim()===""){
        $("#quick-search-input").val(s)
    }
});
$("#quick-search-input").keyup(function(e){
    var t=e.keyCode||e.which,s={up:38,down:40,left:37,right:39,esc:27,enter:13};
    if(t===s.enter||t===s.esc||t===s.up||t===s.down||t===s.left||t===s.right){
        return!1
    };
    var o=$("#quick-search-input").val();
    if(o.length>=3){a(function(){
        $(".ajax-spinner").fadeIn("fast");$.ajax({
            url:"../directsearch",data:{"query":o},type:"post",success:function(e){
                var t="";if(e.status==="ok"){
                    e.data.forEach(function(e){
                        t+="<li><a href=\""+e.url+"\"><img src=\""+e.img+"\"><span>"+e.title+"</span><p>"+e.year+"</p></a></li>"
                    })
                }
                else{
                    t="<li class=\"ac-no-results\">"+e.message+"</li>"
                };
                $(".ac-results ul").html(t);
                if(!$(".ac-results").is(":visible")){
                    $(".ac-results").slideDown()
                };
                $(".ac-results ul li:first-child").addClass("ac-item-hover");
                $(".ac-results ul li:first-child").addClass("ac-item-selected");
                $(".ajax-spinner").fadeOut("fast")},error:function(e){
                    var t="";t="<li class=\"ac-no-results\">Error: "+e.statusText+" (Code "+e.status+")</li>";
                    $(".ac-results ul").html(t);
                    if($(".ac-results").not(":visible")){
                        $(".ac-results").slideDown()
                    };
                    $(".ac-results ul li:first-child").addClass("ac-item-selected");
                    $(".ajax-spinner").fadeOut("fast")
                }
        })
    },500)}
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if($(".ac-results").is(":visible")){
        var o=e.keyCode||e.which,s={
            up:38,down:40,esc:27,enter:13
        };
        if(o===s.esc){$(".ac-results").slideUp();
        return!1};
        if(!$(".ac-results li").hasClass("ac-no-results")){
            var t=$(".ac-results"),
            a=$(".ac-results ul li").hasClass("ac-item-selected"),
            n=$(".ac-results ul li").first().hasClass("ac-item-selected"),
            i=$(".ac-results ul li").last().hasClass("ac-item-selected");
            switch(o){
                case s.up:if(a){
                    if(n){
                        $("li.ac-item-selected",t).removeClass("ac-item-selected");
                        $("ul li",t).last().addClass("ac-item-selected");
                        break
                    };
                    $("li.ac-item-selected",t).prev().addClass("ac-item-selected");
                    $("li.ac-item-selected",t).next().removeClass("ac-item-selected")
                }
                else{
                    $("ul li",t).last().addClass("ac-item-selected")
                };
                break;
                case s.down:if(a){
                    if(i){
                        $("li.ac-item-selected",t).removeClass("ac-item-selected");
                        $("ul li",t).first().addClass("ac-item-selected");
                        break
                    };
                    $("li.ac-item-selected",t).next().addClass("ac-item-selected");
                    $("li.ac-item-selected",t).prev().removeClass("ac-item-selected")
                }
                else{
                    $("ul li",t).first().addClass("ac-item-selected")
                };
                break;
                case s.enter:window.location.href=$("li.ac-item-selected a",t).attr("href");
                break
            }
        }
    }
});
$(document).click(function(e){
    var t=$(e.target);
    if($(".ac-results").is(":visible")&&(0 in t)&&t[0].id!="quick-search-input"&&e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()!=="a"){
        $(".ac-results").slideUp()
    }
});
$(".ac-results ul").on("mouseover","li",function(){
    $(this).addClass("ac-item-selected").siblings().removeClass("ac-item-selected")
});
var a=(function(){
    var e=0;return function(t,s){
        clearTimeout(e);e=setTimeout(t,s)
    }
})
(),
e=0;
setInterval(function(){
    var t=12,s=16,a=e*-s;
    $(".ajax-spinner").css({"backgroundPosition":a+"px 0px"});
    e++;if(e>=t)e=0},100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, check your console with firebug an tell me which error you get form there when you try to search, I want to know the route (I think you have the problem here, but I want to confirm with a capture on console Firebug)

Comment: I getted error for value but I fixed it now...I don't get any error but its saying undefined again..now its the response...Doesn't response that jquery want to get...how can I send the code from php to this jquery..I want the php to send the code. now its posting right but saying undefined..

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your php file? Inside your php file you need to do something like that:

```
<?php

$data = /*get your data*/;

header('Content-Type: application/json');

/*proces your data*/

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Just print this json_encode($data), maybe I don't understand your question... =)